# How to get campaign referrals for both ios and android ( in react native project)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

How to get campaign referrals for both ios and android( in react native project)

To generate a campaign link we have to use
For android:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder
For iOS
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder

For android you just have to have the package name and other campaign related details.
But for ios we need to add the Google Analytics Property ID:  which should be in "UA-XXXX-Y" this format. Where as for firebase projects we will have just the 9 digit Google Analytics Property ID something like "123456789".
If we give that property id to the ios campaign url generator it throws an error saying invalid format asks to give in  "UA-XXXX-Y" this format.

For android i did generate the campaign url from the above link and the results are not shown in firebase but are present in google analytics.

To summarise,  i have these questions. one on how to generate campaign url for ios. and how to capture it for ios.
Other is why is my campaign source not captured in firebase but in google analytics automatically?